# How to fix my msi VerifyReadyDlg install button

Tags: wix, orca

My msi "install" button in the VerifyReadyDlg returns WelcomeDlg.

Wix toolset 3.11

I made a msi installer which contains several customized UI windows based on WixUI_FeatureTree for customizing WelcomeDlg (including reading registry and showing its status in next dialog).

- CustomizedWelcomeDlg
- CheckLicenseKeyAndWebsiteDlg
- CustomizedLicenseAgreementDlg
- VerifyReadyDlg

When I push "install" button on VerifyReadyDlg(not customized), not starting ExecuteSequence but WelcomeDlg (not customized) appears.

How to fix this? Or should I customize VerifyReadyDlg, too?

Perhaps Orca can be used for such "broken" msi UI sequence problem, would you teach me how to troubleshoot seeking its cause?

UI sequence is below.

            1

```
      <!--<Publish Dialog="CustomizedWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="CheckLicenseKeyAndWebsiteDlg">
        NOT Installed
      </Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="CustomizedWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="CheckLicenseKeyAndWebsiteDlg">
        Installed AND PATCH
      </Publish>-->
      <Publish Dialog="CheckLicenseKeyAndWebsiteDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="SetPhysicalPathDlg">
        EVALUATIONFLG = 0
      </Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="CheckLicenseKeyAndWebsiteDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizedLicenseAgreementDlg">
        EVALUATIONFLG = 1
      </Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="CustomizedLicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="SetPhysicalPathDlg">
        CUSTOMIZEDLICENSEACCEPTED = 1
      </Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="SetPhysicalPathDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">
        1
      </Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="SetPhysicalPathDlg" Order="2">
        1
      </Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="SetPhysicalPathDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CheckLicenseKeyAndWebsiteDlg" Order="2">
        1
      </Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="CustomizedLicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CheckLicenseKeyAndWebsiteDlg">
        1
      </Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="CheckLicenseKeyAndWebsiteDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizedWelcomeDlg" />



        <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CheckLicenseKeyAndWebsiteDlg" Order="2">NOT Installed</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizedWelcomeDlg" Order="3">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>


        <UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree" />
        <DialogRef Id="CheckLicenseKeyAndWebsiteDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="SetPhysicalPathDlg" />
```

Below is /l*vx switch log excerpt.

> Action 0:58:03: VerifyReadyDlg。Dialog created
>     MSI (c) (44:B4) [00:58:03:744]: Note: 1: 2727 2:  
>     Action ending. 0:58:04: CustomizedWelcomeDlg。 return value 1。
>     MSI (c) (44:7C) [00:58:04:137]: Skipping action: MaintenanceWelcomeDlg (condition is false)
>     MSI (c) (44:7C) [00:58:04:137]: Skipping action: ResumeDlg (condition is false)
>     MSI (c) (44:7C) [00:58:04:137]: Doing action: WelcomeDlg

Answer (score 0):

After I read Denis Peshkov's Notes: Replacing a standard WelcomeDlg with a custom one.http://www.peshkov.biz/2015/03/replacing-standard-welcomedlg-with.html I added the InstallUISequence section below. Then pushing "install" button works properly to execute sequence. But I still have not understood enough why this turning off the original Welcome Dlg fixed the problem. May I ask you to explain why does it fix?

```xml
   <InstallUISequence>
            <Show Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Before="ProgressDlg" Overridable="no">0</Show>
            <Show Dialog="CustomizedWelcomeDlg" Before="ProgressDlg" >NOT Installed OR PATCH</Show>
        </InstallUISequence>
```